# how to update existing #tblUniqueKeys data along with Identity of #tblMaster

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables #tblMaster and #tblUniqueKeys data with common "MasterId" as PK/FK relationship.

```
create Table #tblMaster (MasterId INT IDENTITY(100,1), Details VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10));
insert into #tblMaster(Details,DetectDate,UpdateBy) values ('DT12', '01/14/2016', 'XYZ')

create Table #tblUniqueKeys (UqId INT IDENTITY(10,1), MasterId INT, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE);
insert into #tblUniqueKeys(MasterId, UniqueKey, DetectDate) values (100, 'uq1', '01/14/2016')
```

Now, I have a table #tblData with data along with "Uniquekey" column.

```
Create Table #tblData (Id int, Details VARCHAR(10),  UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10));
insert into #tblData values (1, 'DT1', 'uq1', '01/15/2016', 'abc')
```

The "Uniquekey" (uq1) already present in table "#tblUniqueKeys" along with Identity "MasterId" from "#tblMaster" table.

Now I need to insert "#tblData" data into "#tblMaster" and after that an Identity generated and I need to update existing #tblUniqueKeys columns data along with "MasterId".

**Current output of tables #tblMaster and #tblUniqueKeys**

[image]

**Seeking for below output,**

[image]

Through **Cursor**, I am able to get my output, but I am looking for some other solution like Merge, etc...

Please note- as demo data, I have 1-1 record in each table, but in my real case, 100-10K data possible. Thanks!!!!

```
Create Table #tblData (Id int, Details VARCHAR(10),  UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10));
insert into #tblData values (1, 'DT1', 'uq1', '01/15/2016', 'abc')

create Table #tblMaster (MasterId INT IDENTITY(100,1), Details VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10));
insert into #tblMaster(Details,DetectDate,UpdateBy) values ('DT12', '01/14/2016', 'abc')

create Table #tblUniqueKeys (UqId INT IDENTITY(10,1), MasterId INT, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DetectDate DATE);
insert into #tblUniqueKeys(MasterId, UniqueKey, DetectDate) values (100, 'uq1', '01/14/2016')

DECLARE @Details VARCHAR(10), @DetectDate DATE, @UpdateBy  VARCHAR(10), @UniqueKey VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @iIdentity INT, @UqId INT
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Details, UniqueKey, DetectDate, UpdateBy  FROM #tblData ORDER BY Id

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Details, @UniqueKey, @DetectDate, @UpdateBy 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
   --#tblMaster TABLE INSERT--
   INSERT INTO #tblMaster(Details, DetectDate, UpdateBy) VALUES (@Details, @DetectDate, @UpdateBy)
   SELECT @iIdentity=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

   --#tblUniqueKeys TABLE UPDATE--
   IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #tblUniqueKeys WHERE UniqueKey = @UniqueKey)
   BEGIN
    SELECT @UqId = UqId FROM #tblUniqueKeys WHERE UniqueKey = @UniqueKey
    UPDATE #tblUniqueKeys SET MasterId = @iIdentity, DetectDate = @DetectDate WHERE UqId = @UqId
   END

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Details, @UniqueKey, @DetectDate, @UpdateBy   
   END   

 CLOSE db_cursor   
 DEALLOCATE db_cursor

 select * from #tblMaster
 select * from #tblUniqueKeys

 DROP TABLE #tblData;
 DROP TABLE #tblMaster;
DROP TABLE #tblUniqueKeys;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `Output` clause you can achieve the desired result.
Follow the below steps.

```
--Creating temp table for storing the Merge output

CREATE TABLE #Output
(
  [Action] NVARCHAR(10),
  InsertedMasterID INT,
  UniqueKey VARCHAR(10),
  DetectDate DATE,
  Tablename VARCHAR(50)
);

GO 

-- Inserting data into #tblmaster using #tblData and getting the required details to #Output table

MERGE INTO #tblMaster a
USING #tblData b
  On a.Details=b.details
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (Details,Detectdate,UpdateBy)
  VALUES(b.Details,b.DetectDate,b.UpdateBy)
   OUTPUT $action,Inserted.MasterID,b.UniqueKey,b.DetectDate,'tblMaster'
    INTO #Output;

--Updating the new masted id and DetectDate  in the table #tblUniqueKeys using the information from #Output table

UPDATE a
 SET a.MasterId=b.InsertedMasterID
     ,a.DetectDate=b.DetectDate
FROM #tblUniqueKeys a
   JOIN  #Output b
         On  a.UniqueKey=b.UniqueKey
```

Output after the update using the given data :

[image]